# Fallo en ruta de contexto - Netbeans -Tomcat

Tags: java, netbeans, apache, tomcat

Creo una aplicacion web desde 0 con todos los valores por defecto, con servidor apache tomcat 8.5 e inmediatamente al crearse el proyecto lo intento arrancar para que me inicie el index.html que se crea por defecto, sin embargo esto no sucede, me aparece lo siguiente.

```
    ant -f "C:\\Users\\chamo\\Desktop\\Programacion\\Java EE\\Carrito" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "-Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\chamo\\Desktop\\Programacion\\Java EE\\Carrito" run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at C:\Users\chamo\Desktop\Programacion\Java EE\Carrito\build\web
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fchamo%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext4849163246449515563.xml&path=/Carrito
FALLO - No pude desplegar la aplicación en ruta de contexto [/Carrito]
C:\Users\chamo\Desktop\Programacion\Java EE\Carrito\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Vuelvo a repetir, este proyecto es completamente nuevo y trae los valores por defecto, lo borre y cree unas dos o tres veces y siempre pasa el mismo error, sin embargo cuando ejecuto proyectos antiguos funcionan sin problemas.

Comment: Se arregla si detienes el servicio en Windows y lo inicias desde NetBeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno en estos días no encontré ninguna solución en cuanto a configuraciones, así que decidí desintalar y reinstalar con la versión mas reciente de Netbeans y me funciono perfecto.